# G is a finite group , U and V are CG modules with characters $\chi_U$ and $\chi_V$, dim(U)=dim(V). Show $\chi_U-\chi_V$ is not a character of G.

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that G is a finite group and that U and V are CG modules whose characters are $\chi_U$ and $\chi_V$ respectively. Suppose that dim(U)=dim(V). Show that $\chi_U-\chi_V$ is not a character of G.

I am not sure how to prove this, in my notes I have a Lemma saying that $\chi_U-\chi_V$ is a character of G, but the lemma doesn't include anything about the dimensions being equal so I assume this is where the Lemma doesn't hold, but I can't see why.

*Suppose that $χ_1, . . . , χ_r$ are the irreducible characters of G, corresponding to the irreducible modules $U_1,…,U_r$. Suppose that χ is a character of G such that $⟨χ,χ_i⟩$ ≥ 1 for some i. Then $χ − χ_i$ is a character of G.*

Thanks

Comment: $\chi(e)$ is dimension, so unless $U,V$ are isomorphic ...

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to hint at

Comment: $\chi_U(e)=\dim U$, $\chi_V(e)=\dim V$, hence $0=(\chi_U -\chi_V)(e)=\dim W$ if $\chi_U-\chi_V=\chi_W$

Comment: okay, thanks i get it, and the same just holds say if dim(v)=dim(u)=n, it just is 0 so it cannot be a character